# How to parse a string containing equal signs to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a string variable

```
let stringValue = "{DATA={VERSION=1.1, STATE=true, STATUS=ONLINE}}"
```

I would like to parse it to object as `result` where `result` will be:

```
let result = {"DATA":{"VERSION":1.1, "STATE": true, "STATUS": "ONLINE"}}
```

How would you convert a `stringValue` to `result` object so it would be possible to access the nested keys?

```
console.log(result.DATA.STATUS)
```

Comment: Where does `stringValue` come from? is it possible to generate it as valid JSON in the first place?

Comment: It is coming from Kafka. We assume we cannot control how the incoming data is formatted.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far to achieve this? Does `stringValue` always have these "keys" or can they vary? Also, it seems odd that some key/value pairs are separated with `=` while one is separated with `:`.

Comment: The incoming `stringValue` contains only the `=` equal signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that keys and string values are fully capitalized:

- I used the regex `/[A-Z]+/g` and `.match(regex)` to get an array of every all caps word in the string.
- Create a `Set` out of the the array to remove duplicates and avoid repeating the next step on the same string multiple times.
- Then iterate over each word and replace it in the main string with itself between quotes. `DATA` => `"DATA"`
- Then replace `=` with `:`
- And finally `JSON.parse()` and we get the object.

```js
let stringValue = "{DATA={VERSION=1.1, STATE=true, STATUS=ONLINE}}";

let regex = /[A-Z]+/g
let objectStrings = stringValue.match(regex)
let uniqueStrings = [... new Set(objectStrings)]

uniqueStrings.forEach((string) => stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll(string, '"'+string+'"'));
stringValue  = stringValue.replaceAll('=', ':');

console.log(JSON.parse(stringValue))
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/jolutaw/edit?js,console) it is in JSBin to show that the keys are properly assigned without the quotes.